# "Applications" launcher not showing, Alt-F2 not working

Tags: unity, lenses

I have just installed ubuntu 11.04 on my ACER 3810T.

Unity is showing only few launchers in the sidebar and the "Applications" launcher is not there. More, if I press Alt-F", not windows (lens) comes up.

Where should I troubleshoot this?

Thanks

PS: Video card: Intel mobile 4 Series Chipset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two launchers wEre not showing in the sidebar because the following packages were missing in the system: **unity-place-files** and **unity-place-applications**.

It was just a matter of installing them, login back and the launchers appered!

Answer (score 0):

Can you open up a terminal session? If so try typing in:

```
unity --reset
```

This will reset Unity to its default settings and hopefully resolve the issue you're having.

Comment: I fixed this by comparing the installation with another pc. My notebook was missing unity-place-applications and unity-place-files packages.I don't know how this could happened during upgrade.

Comment: @Fabio Go ahead and make an answer for your problem with how you solved it so it can help the next person (and we can vote on it!)